# How common is resin/epoxy sealing of space-faring equipment nowadays?

Tags: artificial-satellite, spacecraft, materials, electronics

In the olden days most of space-faring electronics would be embedded in resin. Hey, that's where the term "embedded software" comes from!

That came with a number of advantages like pressure-proofing the system, making it way more durable against accelerations and allowing for more balanced temperature distribution. It also came with a slew of new problems, making the boards unserviceable, heat removal harder at times, and the whole thing much heavier.

How does the situation look like nowadays? How often are electronics meant for space embedded in resin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know for certain epoxy is still used today, perhaps not as commonly as in days past, but still are used. They are mostly used for delicate parts, to keep them from falling off, or otherwise hold them in place. I'm sure they aren't quite as heavily used as in previous days, but I imagine that they are used in almost every spacecraft (Every one that I'm aware of, at least)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty common. Potting doesn’t block airflow (what airflow? …at least not in non Soviet hardware), and it also provides vibration robustness, including damping.

I cracked open a vendor’s space battery pack once, when an issue came up. There was more potting than cells, and that was for fairly durable (mechanically) components inside a metal shell.