# Seeking concept art or photo of MAKS on carrier plane

Tags: conceptual, spaceplane

In an answer to this question [Are the US shuttle and Buran the only space planes to have launched vertically with wings exposed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20727/are-the-us-shuttle-and-buran-the-only-space-planes-to-have-launched-vertically-w) [Schlusstein](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/18744/schlusstein) mentioned the proposed MAKS system, which was new to me.

[image]
(image by By Titutik at Russian Wikipedia, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=29868251)

It sounds pretty interesting but I'm having trouble visualizing how this sat on/was carried by the Antonov 225 carrier plane.  Is there any concept art or photos of how the mated vehicles looked?  My google search has been fruitless - maybe I need some Russian terms.

Comment: Look to [buran.ru](http://www.buran.ru/) - very good site about all space systems with wings

Comment: Almost looks like a launch vehicle for a whale, weird.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

[image: MAKS]

and another [drawing](http://www.buran.ru/htm/molniya6.htm):

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks. That really shows how tiny the orbiter is. (except for that bottom one)

Comment: @OrganicMarble Makes you realize how *big* the Shuttle/Buran were compared to most spaceplane concepts.

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a few drawings in the first link

http://www.buran-energia.com/documentation/documentation-akc-maks-multipurpose.php

Related development: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan-Gurevich_MiG-105

[image: https://2ch.hk/spc/src/242910/14514294138961.jpg]

[image: https://topwar.ru/uploads/posts/2010-09/1283451927_max005c.jpg]

[image: https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-A7lXnZHTuFA/Vs-mEmXL8EI/AAAAAAAAEVI/1WAlR0huv5U/s1600/55097445.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwL1E.jpg]

BOR-4 (related development):
[image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/r4VLRt1fIbA/maxresdefault.jpg]